# Strange code segment from c++

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

Reading code from other posts, I'm seeing something like this.

```
struct Foo {
  Foo() : mem(0) {}
  int mem;
};
```

What does mem(0) {} does in this case, especially regarding the curly brackets? I have never seen this before and have no idea where else I would find out about this. I know that mem(0), would intialize mem to 0, but why the {}?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this weird colon-member syntax in the constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Comment: [Initialization lists on C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `Foo()` is the class' constructor, it must have a body, even if the member variable `mem` is initialized outside of it.

That's why, in your example, the constructor has an empty body:

```
Foo() : mem(0)
{
    // 'mem' is already initialized, but a body is still required.
}
```

Comment: is it ever necessary to code it like this, or a just a matter of style?

Comment: It's can be a matter of style. Some people prefer initialization lists, some prefer assignments in the constructor body. However, the consensus is to [use initialization lists](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6) to avoid temporary object creation in some cases.

Comment: No it is not necessary. Some say it has a better performance but I reckon if at all this effect should be marginal. In my experience it is better to initialize the members IN the body of the constructor. It makes debuggin easier.

Comment: @rubixibuc: Member Initializer list is the way to go, If anyone else tells you otherwise they are grossly wrong.Check out the link I added under the Q.

Comment: @DariuszScharsig: You might also want to refer the link I mentioned in above comment to clear your wrong notion.

Comment: @Darius: you *cannot initialize* members in the body. You can only *assign* to them. This means that if you don't use an initialization list, you're limited to using types that are default constructible, which doesn't always make sense. That is, unless you don't mind adding invalid states to your classes just for the sake of it.

Comment: @Als: I did, not very convincing.

Comment: @DariuszScharsig: I am afraid You did not understand what you read then.

Answer (score 2):

It defines the constructor of the class. The part after the colon is the initialization list, in which the `mem` member is initialized to zero using a constructor call.

Compare:

```
int a(0);
int b = 0;
```

These two do the same, but the former is more in line with how object construction typically looks in C++.

Answer (score 0):

int c++ you can define your method implementation in .h file

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
   MyClass(){
     .....
   }

   void doSomething(){
     .....
   }

   ~MyClass(){
     .....
   }
};
```

Usually it used in templates implementation. Also you could use this method of class declaration in case you would like to avoid libraries linking and you prefer to give to user all your code so he can include your file without linking any lib file to his project.